# Husky (Clearpath) Controller source code

Tags: ros, clearpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking to make some changes in the clearpath_base package for the Husky controller in ROS Hydro. However, I do not see the source files in the ROS directories. How do I get access to the source code? More specifically I am trying to add failsafe states in the controller so when it loses communications it does not continue executing the previous state. Please advise.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130526/husky-(clearpath)-controller-source-code/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2014-03-07**:
We're not always on these forums, but could you go into a little more detail on what you're looking for? What you're describing should be in the controls already. That is, unless you're talking about losing comms with a regular wireless gamepad, which a timeout won't solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this what you are looking for?

https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/clearpath_base

If you're looking for the actual firmware that runs on the motor controllers themselves, you would be best off contacting Clearpath directly - they are very helpful.

---

Originally posted by [mardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/10151/mardo/) with karma: 126 on 2014-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1